# Tinymce hyperlinks are being stripped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I've got a simple `Tinymce` textfield where a user can insert links and text. But when I submit my form, the links just dissapear?! If I inspect the element I can see the links like so:

```
<a title="title" href="https://www.facebook.com" data-mce-href="https://www.facebook.com">IAMDISPLAYED</a>
```

But when I submit my form the following happens:

Instead of adding the:

`<a href='www.THE_LINK_I_ADDED.com'>Text I chose</a>`

It simply adds the `Text to display` without an `<a` tag wrapping it. Like so:

```
Text I chose
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is my `.init` setup:

```
tinymce.baseURL = '/static/tinymce/js/tinymce';
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".tinymce",
    plugins: [
        "searchreplace code link",
        "insertdatetime contextmenu paste"
    ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar1: " undo redo | styleselect | bullist | link",
    theme_advanced_disable: "sup,sub",
    removed_menuitems: 'newdocument,strikethrough,superscript,subscript,bold,italic,underline',
    style_formats: [
        { title: "Header", format: "h2" }
    ],
    valid_children: '-li[h2]',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
valid_children: '-li[h2]',
```

When you submit the editor content tinymce cleans up your editor content using the settings you provided (or the default settings). In this case you did not allow paragraphs with a-Tags as children.
Have a closer look at the use of [valid_elements](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements) and [valid_children](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_children).

I guess if you remove the setting completly your a-Tag won't be stripped as tinymce allows a-Tag by default.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem :\

Comment: Turns out ```tinymce``` may not be the problem, I think it's something to do with Django when it tries to save to mysql, it seems to just strip all but the ```<p>``` tags.